# Adding two more columns to existing script (backup summary)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

[image]Can anyone help me to add two more columns to the existing code? I am not a core developer. I want `backup_size` in GBs and `name` from `msdb.dbo.backupset` table, where `msdb.dbo.backupset.name = **'XXXXXXX'**`. I need this because we are using a third party tool for backups. That tool name is reflecting in msdb.dbo.backupset `name` column, so I want to filter by that name. Please see code below.

```
SELECT name,
       recovery_model_desc,
       state_desc,
       d AS 'Last Full Backup',
       i AS 'Last Differential Backup',
       l AS 'Last log Backup'
 FROM (SELECT db.name,
              db.state_desc,
              db.recovery_model_desc,
              type,
              backup_finish_date
        FROM   master.sys.databases db
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset a ON a.database_name = db.name
       ) AS Sourcetable 
 PIVOT (MAX(backup_finish_date) FOR type IN ( D, I, L )) AS MostRecentBackup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name , recovery_model_desc , state_desc , d AS 'Last Full Backup' , i AS 'Last Differential Backup' , l AS 'Last log Backup' , backupname
, Cast(backupsizeGB AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) backupsizeGB
FROM 
( SELECT db.name , db.state_desc , db.recovery_model_desc , a.type , LastBackupFinishedDate, b.name backupname, (b.backup_size /1024 / 1024 /1024) as backupsizeGB
FROM master.sys.databases db 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select database_name dBase, type, max(backup_finish_date) LastBackupFinishedDate From msdb.dbo.backupset group By database_name, type)
 a ON a.dBase = db.name 
    Left outer join msdb.dbo.backupset b on b.database_name=a.dBase and backup_finish_date= LastBackupFinishedDate
) AS Sourcetable 
PIVOT ( MAX(LastBackupFinishedDate) FOR type IN ( D, I, L ) ) AS MostRecentBackup
```

This cleaned it up for me.
Can't do a true pivot (Placing the dates of each on one line) because the filenames and sizes prevent it.

Comment: Thanks @RObWaibel,It helped me to fetch exact data.Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to tweak this for your needs

```
SELECT bs.database_name AS DbName
    ,CAST(bs.backup_size / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS BackupSize_GB
    ,bs.backup_start_date AS Backup_StartDate
    ,bs.backup_finish_date AS Backup_EndDate
    ,bs.NAME AS BackupName
    ,bmf.physical_device_name AS DeviceName
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
WHERE bs.database_name = 'DB_Name'
  AND  bs.NAME = 'BackupSetName'
ORDER BY bs.backup_start_date DESC
```

Comment: Hi @Scott,I checked this one.It adds two new columns I needed but gives no result somehow.can you please help me

Comment: Did you change the 'DB_Name' literal to your database name and change bs.NAME to the backupset name you are looking for?

Comment: Yes sir I did do that.

Comment: Comment line `AND  bs.NAME = 'BackupSetName'` and check the result

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query modified with the 2 columns.

```
SELECT name , recovery_model_desc , state_desc , d AS 'Last Full Backup' , i AS 'Last Differential Backup' , l AS 'Last log Backup' , backupname, Cast(backupsizeGB AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) backupsizeGB
FROM 
( SELECT db.name , db.state_desc , db.recovery_model_desc , type , backup_finish_date, a.name backupname, a.backup_size /1024 / 1024 / 1024 as backupsizeGB
FROM master.sys.databases db 
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset a ON a.database_name = db.name 
Where a.name = 'BackupSetName') AS Sourcetable 
PIVOT ( MAX(backup_finish_date) FOR type IN ( D, I, L ) ) AS MostRecentBackup
```

Comment: Hi @WEI_DBA,it shows the two new columns but gives no result under the columns.can you please let me know sir

Comment: Try querying the backupset table alone using, Select name, backup_size From msdb.dbo.backupset Where name = 'DBName' and see what you get.

Comment: The multipart identifier "a.name" could not be found.

Comment: I removed that. Sorry, copy paste error on my part. See my edited statement above.

Comment: Actually DBname is supposed to be the backup set name. See edited code in the block area above in the answer.

Comment: it gives me 736 rows.how can I get the rows ordered by backup_finish_date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44787/discussion-between-sqlboy-and-wei-dba).